# What is the equivalent of Juniper's " monitor start *logfile* " command for Cisco devices?

Tags: syslog

I enjoy having the feature of being able to watch real time logs as they occur, but I cannot figure out for the life of me what the Cisco equivalent command for " *monitor start logfile* " as it is on a Juniper device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`logging monitor` in configuration mode will give you live logging on a SSH or Telnet access. you can set the logging level after monitor, for instance `logging monitor debugging` will give you everything. On console access it's `logging console debugging` as an example. Use `no` in front of the command to disable.

Comment: Be super careful with this in older IOS-based devices.  While Junos has lots of protection in place so that logging doesn't overwhelm the routing engine, the same cannot be said for older Cisco routers and switches.  With too much logging enabled, you can bring the router/switch down to the point where you can't even manage it any more